# Java sqlite sql syntax error

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

Using this sql in my java code doesn't work and give a sql execption

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `homes` (`home_naam` varchar(20) NOT NULL,`speler` varchar(20) NOT NULL,`wereld` varchar(20) NOT NULL, `locatiex` int(11) NOT NULL,`locatiey` int(11) NOT NULL,`locatiez` int(11) NOT NULL, KEY t(`home_naam`,`speler`))
```

The error is: java.sql.SQLException: near "`home_naam`": syntax error

What I am doing wrong? I searched the web but no result.

Comment: `key` -> `primary key`

Comment: Does SQLite really support the non-standard backtick ` quoting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define what key you want (PRIMARY, UNIQUE) and remove the name of it

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `homes` 
(
  `home_naam` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `speler` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `wereld` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `locatiex` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `locatiey` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `locatiez` int(11) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`home_naam`,`speler`)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a composite primary key, change

```
...  KEY t(`home_naam`,`speler`)
```

to

```
... PRIMARY KEY(`home_naam`,`speler`)
```